# Migrating from Python 3.4 to Python 3.6 AMI

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

Does anyone have a process for migrating an Elastic Beanstalk environment from an existing Python 3.4 instance to a Python 3.6 instance?

By saving my configuration and changing the "EC2 image ID" (under Configuration -> Instances)  to that of a Python 3.6 AMI platform instance, it looks like I was able to spin up a new EC2 instance with a Python 3.6 AMI (I see aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2018.03.0.x86_64-python36-hvm-201805090750 (ami-b5342ad5) listed in my EC2 instance details). I believe this involved destroying my Elastic Beanstalk environment and bringing a new one up from the configuration backup.

It looks like I now have an EC2 instance with an Python 3.6 AMI, however, when I run `eb config` I see it still listed as a Python 3.4 instance. And it otherwise behaves as it is still a Python 3.4 instance (the virtualenv is still 3.4).

I saw this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=830316) stating that the `PlatformArn` needs to be updated. Mine says

`PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Python 3.4 running on 64bit
  Amazon Linux/2.7.0`

I tried changing the "3.4" to a "3.6" with no success. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that `eb config` indeed did not work. Alternatively, you could also try `eb upgrade`

Comment: @progfan - Thank you for the suggestion! Yes, I believe `eb config` did fail. I have already performed an `eb upgrade`, which allowed me to upgrade the underlying Amazon Linux OS, however, it does not allow someone to jump from one pre-configured environment to another (ex. Python 3.4 on Amazon Linux to Python 3.6 on Amazon Linux). This has been the crux of my problem.

Comment: Okay, can you post the error message associated with the `eb config` failure? You can find more detailed information if you do `eb config --debug`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem.

There is presently no such Python 3.6 `PlatformArn` as the following in `us-west-1`:

```
arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.0
```

You can determine the list of PlatformArns in `us-west-1` at your disposal by performing:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions --region us-west-1 | grep "PlatformArn"
```

Depending on your account access rules/permissions, you should be able to see:

```
arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.0
```

in the result of the `list-platform-versions` API call. The difference, which is subtle, is the trailing "2.6.0", instead of "2.7.0", which you tried.

Comment: Thanks again for the follow up! From the elasticbeanstalk web interface I was able to spin up an instance of Python 3.6 on Amazon Linux 2.7.0. I do see what you are pointing out though - I also did not see this version listed under `list-platform-versions`. I ended up just spinning up a new environment entirely instead of trying to update an existing environment, which at some point I saw wasn't actually supported, but I tried anyway. I ended up running into an error with a pre-configuration step however - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282974&tstart=0

Comment: At the moment, I am holding off on upgrading to the Python 3.6 platform, however, I am still eager to do so once I am able to figure it out.